# Project Fails to Load with VisualSVN Error Message

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visualsvn

VS2013 was working fine this morning.  After a break, I came back to my desk and tried to open another instance of Visual Studio 2013.

I received an error message along the lines of

VisualSVN Cannot Load

It directed me to look at

> C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml

for additional information.

After dismissing the dialog box, the project was not loaded, showing a GUID in place of the project name.  ActivityLog.xml contains

> SetSite failed for package [VisualSVN]
>
> SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]
>
> End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]

How can I get Visual Studio to load my project again?

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to VisualSVN that fixes this issue.  Not sure why this broke in the middle of the day.  Perhaps my SVN provider updated the SVN server version while I was away from my desk.

Download the latest client version and you should be back in business.